# Error:File 'workspace.xml' is readonly, but miss svn:needs-lock property: Android Studio 2.2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I have checked out a project from SVN into the Android Studio where the gradle sync fails with the following error:

```
Error:File 'workspace.xml' is readonly, but miss svn:needs-lock property.
```

Additional error says,

```
Failed to resolve: com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+
Failed to resolve: de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0
Failed to resolve: com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1
```

I can't make the gradle sync work.
Please, can anyone help?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @KamranAhmed I am using Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following these steps:

- Open terminal and navigate to your project directory
- Execute `sudo chmod -R +rw *`

That should fix your issue.

Comment: This helped and also I had issues with Apache ports. Followed your solution and got the ports opened. It is fixed now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

i have solution for you
first of all close everything android studio
then go to terminal
then sudo and android path ./studio.sh then enter and enter password your problem solved because some time before i was same problem and stuck android studio.
if you not getting then upload screenshot